# Delete a row in a table triggers a deletion in an other table

Tags: database, oracle

I have a strange issue. When a deletion is performed in a table I got a deletion in another table!

I executed this command to search for all triggers in the database, but I didn't find any.

```
select * from ALL_TRIGGERS;
```

How can I investigate this issue?

Comment: Yes, there is a foreign key !!! you saved my life man @APC

Comment: you're welcome. Cascading deletes are one of those things which it are easy to forget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there is a foreign key constraint between the two tables? If so, is it defined as ON DELETE CASCADE?

This query will find foreign keys referencing a primary or unique key on YOUR_TABLE_NAME (which is the table you targeted with your delete).

```
select r.table_name
       , r.constraint_name as foreign_key
       , r.delete_rule
from all_constraints r
     join all_constraints p
     on p.owner = r.r_owner and p.constraint_name = r.r_constraint_name
where r.constraint_type = 'R'
and p.constraint_type in ('U', 'P')
and p.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
/
```

The DELETE_RULE will show you whether the deletion of a parent record is cascaded to the dependent records.